# Using PhantomJS for Selenium's htmlsuite

Tags: selenium, webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver, htmlsuite

Trying to port selenese commands from the Selenium IDE to a cron-usable task, and have gotten as far as getting these to run with Webdriver's HTMLSuite command using a local installation of Firefox. However, we need these to run without opening a visual browser - as we're already using PhantomJS elsewhere in the application this seemed like the logical option rather than going down the XVFB route.

Is this possible? I've tried a variety of commands but keep getting errors of phantomjs not being an accepted browser.

Comment: have you figured this out or is it impossible to execute selenium ide suites with phantomJS?